# Extract select statement from log file using python

Tags: python

I need to extract select statement from log using python. Basically I want to search for string "Select" and then extract current and next 2-3 lines till last question mark is available so that I get complete select statement example query:

```
select first_name, last_name from table t1 where t1.id = ? and t1.code = ?
```

This is how log file is:

```
2020-06-04 21:04:59,661 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.test.bs.engine.Action                       ] Choose engine based on parameters: jobid='1A23456789', jobcode=null
2020-06-04 21:04:59,662 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.test.bs.engine.Action                        ] Performing existence check for object_id='1AE1C4321' using sql: select first_name from employees where employee_id=?
2020-06-04 21:04:59,662 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.sql.ConnectionProviderJBoss            ] --> Using DB connection from pool java:jboss/datasources: [#21837933]
2020-06-04 21:04:59,665 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.sql.ConnectionProviderJBoss              ] <-- Connection [#21837933] returned to DB pool. Statement=[closed]. ResultSet=[closed].
```

Comment: Please add a more reasonable data sample to help create such a python regex!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Done, comment is edited, please check

Comment: Can you not just open the log file in a text editor and copy the parts you are interested in?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It has around 2,000 select statements and notepad takes longer to even open it. Manually copying all of them is impossible :-)

Comment: Did you try to write some code to do what you want? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Are you working on the query command itself or the post sample as I don't see the text "Select" in any part of that text.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen check second line the "select" starts at the end of line after "sql: "

Comment: I see and that is how the output is?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes, it has plenty of select statements generated in log and sometimes they run from first to 2-3 lines and the way to determine that select statement ended is by checking for last ? symbol after select starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample data this is the code used:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"select.*\?\n.*\n.*")
try:
    with open('log.txt') as f:
        line = f.read()
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
            print(f'lines: {match.group()}')
except Exception as e_rr:
    print('Error: {}'.format(e_rr))
```

and the result:

```
select first_name from employees where employee_id=?
         2020-06-04 21:04:59,662 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.sql.ConnectionProviderJBoss            ] --> Using DB connection from pool java:jboss/datasources: [#21837933]
         2020-06-04 21:04:59,665 Worker-9 DEBUG [com.sql.ConnectionProviderJBoss              ] <-- Connection [#21837933] returned to DB pool. Statement=[closed]. ResultSet=[closed].
```

Comment: Tried but it says   File "<stdin>", line 5
    print(f'lines: {match.group()}')

Comment: If that doesn't work use ```print('lines: {}'.format(match.group())```